# How to apply .toFixed(2)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and searched for a while to fix my problem.
I know the solution should be .toFixed(2) added to my code

```
jQuery("#price").html("Price : $" + "<strike>" + total /0.75 + ".00" + " USD" + "</strike>" );
    jQuery("#priced").html("Save : $" + total /0.75/100*25 + ".00" + " USD"  + " (25%)");
```

I tried different ways but can not get it to work.
The results now showing 12 decimal numbers, I need only 2

*** UPDATE ***

Well, this is my first question and its now more then 1.5 years ago I asked it.
It received some bad votes and its time to change it.

The answer that would have helped me would have been

```
(total/0.75).toFixed(2)
```

instead of

```
total/0.75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toFixed is bound to the prototype in Number, so it's easy as this.

```
let aNumber = 10.111;
aNumber.toFixed(2);
```